# How to update e2fsck correctly?

Tags: boot, fsck

I just migrated a linux system (Ubuntu 16.04) from a failing hard disk. After lots of troubles, it starts up, but always complains

```
/dev/sda2 has unsupported feature(s): metadata_csum
E2FSCK: Get a newer version of e2fsck!
```

So I updated e2fsck to 1.44.4 *on my root file system*.

```
e2fsck 1.44.4 (18-Aug-2018)
Using EXT2FS Library version 1.44.4, 18-Aug-2018
```

Still I get the above error.

So my question is: From where is e2fsck run at startup? It appears not to be the root partition. Do I have to update e2fsck on the initramfs? Is it possible that reinstalling grub2 updates e2fsck on the initramfs? Reinstalling grub2 did not solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read this very detailed Ask Ubuntu post :
[E2FSCK: how to handle the “metadata_csum” error by advancing the e2fsck version beyond default installed version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1053404/e2fsck-how-to-handle-the-metadata-csum-error-by-advancing-the-e2fsck-version?noredirect=1&lq=1)

The final advice given is :

> update e2fsprogs and e2fslibs to 1.43.X - do not go all the way up to 1.44.X.
>   The 1.43.X packages are sufficient to remove the "metadata_csum" error and allow you to use GParted or e2fsck at the command line.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. I had e2fsck 1.44 and e2fslibs 1.42. The post install triggers generated a new initramfs